# Speed up a nested Python loop while updating a dictionary

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have the following Python nested loop and trying to decrease its execution time. I have tried a few optimizations but don't help much. I was wondering if someone can give some hints or if there is any Pythonic way or etc.

```
def(input_list, A, B, threshold):
   a_dict = {}
   idx = 0
   for sc, nb in zip(A, B):
       b_dict = {}
       for s, n in zip(sc, nb):
           if s >= threshold:
                b_dict.update(init_dict(n, s))
       a_dict[input_list[idx]] = b_dict
       idx += 1 
   return a_dict
```

both A and B are `numpy.ndarray`.

For example, one of the optimizations I tried was to avoid the function call to init_dict(n,s) and directly update the b_dict without needing having a function call and creating another dictionary inside it, return it and then update the b_dict, which helps a bit. But any more optimization to avoid two loops for example or using multiprocessing or threading?

A is something like this:

```
 [[0.8921996  0.91602445 0.92908716 0.9417222  0.96200365]
  [0.4753568  0.6385271  0.6559716  0.67830306 0.7077361 ]
  [0.700236   0.75287104 0.7589616  0.7638799  0.77096677]
  ....
 ]
```

and B is:

```
 [[682506892 693571174 668887658 303551993  27694382]
  [ 15028940  14862639  54801234  14711873  15136693]
  [567664619 217092797 399261625 124879790 349055820]
  ....
 ]
```

The returned value (a_dict), is something like this:

```
 {
  '147840198': {
   '567664619': 0.7002360224723816, '217092797': 0.752871036529541, 
   '399261625': 0.7589616179466248, '124879790': 0.7638798952102661, 
   '349055820': 0.7709667682647705
   }, 
  '485045174': {
   '627320584': 0.24876028299331665, '297801439': 0.3101433217525482, 
   '166126424': 0.3392677307128906, '579653715': 0.3781401515007019, 
   '880315906': 0.40654435753822327
   }, 
  '39703998': {
   '273891679': 0.667972981929779, '972073794': 0.8249127864837646, 
   '17236820': 0.8573702573776245, '675493278': 0.8575121164321899, 
   '163042687': 0.8683345317840576
   }, 
  '55375077': {
   '14914733': 0.7121858596801758, '28645587': 0.7306985259056091, 
   '14914719': 0.7347514629364014, '15991986': 0.7463902831077576, 
   '14914756': 0.7500130534172058
   },
   .....
 }
```

`_init_dict(n,s)` is a function that gets n and s as key and value, respectively and returns a dictionary. As I mentioned, earlier, that step is not needed and we can directly use n and s, as key-value pair for b_dict.

`threshold` can be a number between zero and one and `input_list` is a list of strings such as bellow:

```
 ['147840198', '485045174', '39703998', '55375077', ....]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here, in words?

Comment: I have two 2D numpy arrays, A and B;  I want to build a dictionary which its keys are from a given input list (using idx) and its values are dictionaries that their keys and values are from A and B considering a threshold on values in A. I put an example, for A and B in the question as well.

Comment: That's not a good explanation.  You should show us what the output would look like for a few samples.  I suspect what you want can be done efficiently using numpy operations that work on the whole array at once, but it's still too hard to tell.

Comment: I put the returned response, a_dict, in the explanation. which is a dictionary (map) of dictionaries.

Comment: I can see one micro-optimization: instead of using `update`, you can just do `b_dict[str(n)] = s`, but there's probably no dramatic speedup possible here.

Comment: Are the values in your sub-lists in A guaranteed to be sorted as they are in your example?  If so, you could certainly replace the inner loop...

Comment: Also, as a courtesy to those who might try your code, you should endeavor to make sure is is reproducible (with some data), error free (needs a function name), and has dependencies included (`init_dict` ??)

Comment: Thanks Tim, you're right and I already applied that.

Comment: Thanks AirSquid, I added more information to the question. Yes, the A sub-lists seems to be sorted, since they are from faiss.read_index() which find the k-nearest neighbors that is logical to be a sorted listed of neighbors from nearest to the farest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so given that the sub-lists in A are sorted, this collapses down pretty quickly.  Anytime you are looking for a threshold within a sorted list, looping is a **BAD** idea.  Bisection search is usually the weapon of choice.

Here are a couple (progressively better) variations on your code.  `chopper3()` gets this down to a 1-liner with a dictionary comprehension

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def chopper(output_keys, A, B, threshold):
    a_dict = {}
    for idx, (sc, nb) in enumerate(zip(A, B)):
        b_dict = {}
        chop_idx = bisect_left(sc, threshold)
        a_dict[output_keys[idx]] = {k:v for k,v in zip(nb[chop_idx:], sc[chop_idx:])}
    return a_dict

def chopper2(output_keys, A, B, threshold):
    chop_idx = [bisect_left(a, threshold) for a in A]
    res = {output_key: dict(zip(k[chop_idx:], v[chop_idx:])) for 
        output_key, v, k, chop_idx in zip(output_keys, A, B, chop_idx)}
    return res
    
def chopper3(output_keys, A, B, threshold):
    return {output_key: dict(zip(k[chop_idx:], v[chop_idx:])) 
            for output_key, v, k in zip(output_keys, A, B) 
            for chop_idx in (bisect_left(v, threshold),)}


A = [   [0.50, 0.55, 0.70, 0.80],
        [0.61, 0.71, 0.81, 0.91],
        [0.40, 0.41, 0.42, 0.43]]

B = [   [123, 456, 789, 1011],
        [202, 505, 30, 400],
        [90, 80, 70, 600]]

output_keys = list('ABC')

print (chopper(output_keys, A, B, 0.55))
print (chopper2(output_keys, A, B, 0.55))
print (chopper3(output_keys, A, B, 0.55))
```

#### Yields:

```
{'A': {456: 0.55, 789: 0.7, 1011: 0.8}, 'B': {202: 0.61, 505: 0.71, 30: 0.81, 400: 0.91}, 'C': {}}
{'A': {456: 0.55, 789: 0.7, 1011: 0.8}, 'B': {202: 0.61, 505: 0.71, 30: 0.81, 400: 0.91}, 'C': {}}
{'A': {456: 0.55, 789: 0.7, 1011: 0.8}, 'B': {202: 0.61, 505: 0.71, 30: 0.81, 400: 0.91}, 'C': {}}
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is great. If I want to convert the key in the inner dictionary to str and its values to float I cannot use chopper3 and chopper2, but I can do it in chopper1. `{str(k):float(v) for k,v` .... Also do you think any parallelization can be done on this code? for example, dividing the inputs (A and B) to different chucks then each chuck is handled by a different thread. Multiprocessing won't help much since they all need to update a shared memory location (the output dictionary). What do you think?

Comment: The inner values are already float type.  if you want to make the inner keys str, I would just use a list comprehension as the first line in the function to convert them all at once.  `B = [str(b) for b in B]`.  And if this answered your question, you could accept the answer.  Good luck!

Comment: B is a list of list and too convert each element of it to str it’s going to be in a nested loop. Also I have to convert the keys to float since they are float32. Again thanks for your response which helps with the performance. However I was looking for higher speed up maybe using threading or other pythonic methods.

Comment: Oh that’s right on B…. My bad.  You can try multi-threading it, but the lists would have to be huge to make it worthwhile.  Give it a go.  Also, by converting B to strings, you’re going to consume much more memory.